# Which Magento Basic Theme Should I make Parent for Designing Responsive theme from scratch

Tags: magento-1.9, theme, parent-child-theme

I want to Design Magento Theme from scratch. I used RWD as Parent but it's much more conflicting with my custom CSS. So I want any idea to create Magento responsive theme.

My theme will have only Category Listing, Product View and Home. And rest I want to use of Magento.

So which theme I should to chose for designing Magento responsive theme. 
I use this http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/ce19-ee114/RWD_dev-guide.html for creating custom theme from scratch in Magento. But in RWD CSS have much more classes. So it's conflicting with my classes. And my designer not able to solve that.

So I want to any Basis Theme by which I can create my theme using parent.

Which Should I use: Base, Modern or Blank. I do not want to design whole theme. I want to design only Product view, Listing, layered and home.

Answer (score 1):

All standard Magento themes have classes for all pages, RWD just adds some responsive classes. To be honest, if your frontend dev has issues with that you might need to find a better dev.

RWD is probably the best theme to get started with, otherwise try blank.